# Qbs cannot get PWD file on MacOS

Tags: macos, pwd, qbs

I want to use my script as `cpp.compilerWrapper: ["../../script"]`

I'm using relative path (from my `.qbs` file) to point the script. It works OK na linux. but on macOS doesn't.

Also when I'm using
`var path = Environment.getEnv("PWD")` on linux return correct path. but on macOS just `/`.

Anyone haS idea why it doesn't work on macOS or maybe know to get this path in other way ?

Comment: Ok. There is the `path` property that gives you the directory the current 
file is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works only by accident. You should not rely on relative paths in that context. Instead, say:
cpp.compilerWrapper: [path + "/../../script"]

Comment: Yeah, ok, but how will I know what `path` is ? I don't want it to be hardcoded. Getting working dir doesn't work on macos. I also tried:


`var process = new Process();`

`var exitCode = process.exec("pwd", [], false);`
`path = process.readLine();`
`process.close();`

`path` also is  `/` on macos.

Comment: "path" is a predefined variable that corresponds to the directory the qbs file is in.